# How do I access multiple SQL Server databases in an instance from Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I've created an ODBC connection, and it works fine. My issue is about accessing more than one database on the same SQL Server instance from Oracle. I had ideally not wanted to create multiple DSNs/config changes.

Is this possible to do from Oracle? No is fine, I just want to know.

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
FROM BobDole.dbo.BobDole@linkedserver AS a 
JOIN BobDole2.dbo.BobDole@linkedserver AS b
WHERE b.col3 = 123;
```

Or even better, if it exists, an `OPENQUERY()` allowing dynamic SQL from Oracle->SQL Server so I don't have to join across the linked server.

Comment: Use a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm)?

Comment: @MT0, I updated the post (sorry it's my first one) to clarify.  I want to access multiple databases on the same instance in SQL Server from Oracle.  I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the db link would allow that.  Thank you!

Comment: If you use the openquery function, you write the Oracle SQL directly.

Comment: With two database links, the problem may be solved. Did you tested it?

Comment: @Msf vtp, I think that this is going to be the solution.  Thank you for confirming.  Another option I have is to create a separate database on the linked SQL Server containing views pointing to the tables needed in the other databases, then enabling cross-database ownership chaining.

Comment: @JaMilz Yes creating view is good idea too, but I prefer separated database link. Because creating database link has lower cost than creating multiple views.